# Pandas DataFrame - how to perform stats on a selection of previous rows whilst iterating over DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having to iterate over a datetime indexed DataFrame (yes, I'm aware that iteration is looked down upon in the pandas community)

I know how to iterate over using `iterrows()`, but that doesn't seem to allow me to "look back" to previous rows.

Here is my code:

```
data = [
['2018-04-25 18:37:00',       5862,        4427],
['2018-04-25 21:36:30',       6421,        4581],
['2018-04-25 22:13:00',       5948,        4779],
['2018-04-26 00:11:30',       5703,        4314],
['2018-04-26 02:27:00',       4988,        3868],
['2018-04-26 04:28:30',       4812,        3823],
['2018-04-26 06:22:30',       4347,        3672],
['2018-04-26 10:50:30',       3896,        3546],
['2018-04-26 12:04:30',       3478,        3557],
['2018-04-26 14:02:30',       3625,        3598],
['2018-04-26 15:31:30',       3751,        3606]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['datetime', 'discharge1', 'discharge2'])
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df = df.set_index('datetime')

then iterate over index, and values:

for i, v in df.iterrows():
    print(f"{i},{v}")
```

**BUT**, I need to do two things:

1. Get the integer position (i.e. row number) for a specified date
2. Perform a statistical function over a selection of previous rows. For the sake of simplicity, let's say, I want to find the MAX value in the **PREVIOUS** 5 row values in column 'A', as I iterate through the rows.

What I want to do is something like this (pseudocode):

```
start_datetime='2018-04-26 00:11:30'
start_pos = df.get_index_position_for_datetime(start_datetime)

for i in range(start_pos, len(df)):
    value = df.iloc[i,'discharge1'] - get_average_over(df.iloc[i,'discharge2']:df.iloc[i-5,'discharge2'])
```

How do I write this - and is it at all possible (or even necessary) to use vectorisation in this case?

Comment: Take a look at the `shift` method of pandas dataframes https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

Comment: Question, what about if there are no 5 records previously, for example just 3?

Comment: @jcaliz I have error checking in my real code

Comment: Added an edit, there was an error in the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) and apply mean:

```
N = 5

df['value'] = df['discharge1'] - df['discharge2'].rolling(N).mean()

location = df.index.get_loc(start_datetime)
df.loc[df.index > start_datetime, 'value'] = np.nan
```

Comment: I liked your previous (one line) answer better. This is doing too much, and would need to much reworking to refactor back into my code which is more complicated than the example I showed here. Also, how about how to get the starting position `start_pos` ?

Comment: Yeah I forgot about the start position so I had to modify the code to support the `start_datetime`

Comment: I think there is no need to shift values. Only subtracting rolling mean would do the job. @jcaliz

Comment: A simpler way would be `df.loc[df.index < start_datetime, 'value'] = np.nan` @jcaliz. Less than.